# Apply Css to multiple class

Tags: css

In my HTML template I have some CSS generated classes like :

- .term-1-2
- .term-2-2
- .term-10-0-1

Ho can I create a CSS class to include all letters after "term" like :

- .term-*

How is it possible in css ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[class*="term-"] { /* your rules here */ }
```

This is called **attribute selector**.

It reads

*"Apply the following rules to any element with a `class` attribute that has `term-` in it."*

Please note that this would also match e.g. `<div class="regular-term-a">`. If that is a problem, go with @Roko C. Buljan's answer.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 1):

Use this rather complicated selector:

```
[class^="term-"], [class*=" term-"] {

}
```

to make sure you're targeting both

- `^=` **Starts with** `"term-"` i.e: `class="term-1-2 foo bar baz"`
- `*=` **Contains** (notice the leading space!) `" term-"` i.e: `class="foo bar term-1-2 baz"`

[MDN: Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)